# How to decode chars in Python respectively?

Tags: python, string, decode, encode

I have tried this problem

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
s = "Ñ ÑÑÑÐ°Ñ! Ð½ÐµÑ ÑÐ¸Ð»"
e = s.encode('ascii')
print e
```

but it gives me this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/unicode.py", line 3, in <module>
    e = s.encode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I get the text to be readable? I have been trying for hours! Not sure how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What output did you _expect_ here?

Comment: my output is я устаю! нет сил or any other foreign language, but also the contents contains symbols and stuff aswell. im parsing the codes from an xml file on the web. When i use a utf-8 header in php it works fine, but when i remade my program in python its been absolute hell. What i've given you in the first box is exactly what the xml parser throws to me. Hopefully i've given you a better idea of what is happening/what i need to be done. thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to encode that Cyrillic to ASCII (which only supports English text)? What did you expect that to do? If you don't want ASCII, why are you asking for it?

Comment: Why does php encode everything correctly but python doesn't?  i've tried giving it utf-8 encoding with no luck. works fine in php with the utf-8 header but its not working in python!

Comment: If you ask PHP to encode Cyrillic text to ASCII, it gives you an error too. Presumably your PHP code works because you didn't do that. If you port the same code to Ruby and try to convert the Cyrillic text to an int, that'll also fail—not because Ruby has problems, but because converting text to an int makes no more sense than converting non-ASCII text to ASCII.

Comment: So.. how do i convert it to readable text?

Comment: It's hard to say, because I don't know how you broke the text in the first place. My guess is you did something like decoding ISO-8859-5 as ISO-9859-1, encoded it to UTF-16-LE, threw away every other byte, then decoded it as Latin-1 again. But whatever you did, you've clearly lost the actual information; most of what you have is just `Ñ`, and that's not going to decode to anything meaningful. Print out the actual bytes you received, as bytes, before whatever you did to mess it up, and we can probably figure out how to decode it to the right text.

Comment: How would i do that? If you can explain how to get the bytes, i'll give you the bytes.

Comment: I don't know where your bytes came from. In the code you've shown us, they came from a literal in your source code that doesn't have the actual string you want, which isn't very useful. Without knowing how you came up with that literal in the first place, I can't tell you how to do something different with whatever you have. But if you've got, say, a `str` named `s` that came off the network somewhere that you haven't touched yet, `print`ing or `log`ging `repr(s)` or `list(bytearray(s))` instead of `s` itself will probably do it.

Comment: It just passed it :/ i never did anything to it. http://pastebin.com/UBcfjUH4 here is the pastebin source if you want to take a look and run it, btw im using python 2.7 if that makes a difference! Goodluck.

Comment: after messing around with it, i ended up encoding the body variable aka the xml to utf-8 then unquoting it, and it works fine now :) shows everything :DDDD Sorry for the painful journey lol.

Answer (score 1):

You have a whole slew of problems here.

First, you've stuck Unicode characters into a `str` literal instead of a `unicode` literal. That's almost always a bad idea.

Second, you've called `encode` on a `str`. But `encode` is for converting `unicode` to `str`.<sup>*</sup> In order to do that, Python has to first `decode` your `str` to a `unicode` so that it can call `encode` on it. And if you force Python to `decode` for you without telling it which codec to use, it will use `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which is almost never what you want. (In particular, it's not going to be UTF-8 just because your source encoding is.)

You can fix those first two problems just by adding one letter:

```
s = u"Ñ ÑÑÑÐ°Ñ! Ð½ÐµÑ ÑÐ¸Ð»"
```

---

But it's still not going to work. Why? Because you're asking it to encode non-ASCII characters into the ASCII character set. Which is impossible. So it's going to call the error handler. Since you didn't specify an error handler, you get the default, called `strict`. As the name implies, `strict` raises an exception when you ask it do something impossible.

There are other error handlers—see the [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) docs for a full list. I'm not sure what output you were expecting, but you can get backslash-escaped text, or text with all the non-ASCII characters replaced by `?`s, or a few other possibilities. For example:

```
e = s.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

Of course if you didn't actually want ASCII, but rather UTF-8, then everything is easy: just tell Python you want UTF-8 instead of ASCII:

```
e = s.encode('utf-8')
```

---

<sub>* There are a few special codecs, like `hex` and `gzip`, that convert `str` to `str`, `unicode` to `unicode`, or `str` to `unicode`, but `ascii` isn't one of them.</sub>